# How to grab specific array and put on specific table in Excel

Tags: excel, match, dropdown, vlookup

I want to grab some array depend on specific string.

```
Name    Qty Request
Fruits  Apples  54  100
Fruits  Bananas 43  100
Fruits  Lemons  41  100
Fruits  Pears   13  50
Vegetable   Cucumber    5   50
Vegetable   Kale    10  50
```

I want to make some table on other sheet and become like this

```
Pick Type   Vegetable
Cucumber    5   50
Kale    10  50
```

Which Vegetable text is dropdown

I know how to update dropdown and get array `B6:D7` using MATCH but I don't know show them as a table.

Comment: Can you please provide more information?  ...or am I to assume that you will always be copying the 2nd to 4th Columns of the 6th and 7th row and copying them to the same location on the other sheet,   Remember that nobody here has seen your spreadsheet before; you need to start at the beginning.  Also,have you made some attempt to solve this on your own, perhaps with the Macro Recorder? If you're stuck on ta certain step, please clarify. Also, to create a new table out of data in cells, you just select (highlight) the data and hit CTRL+T.

Comment: From the description you give, a Pivot Table would do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How about a Pivot Table?**

> As with many questions here, Excel already has inbuilt functionality
>   for this. In this case it is actually better to use, than the formulas, since > the table will auto-update itself, even if there's new
>   item added.

1. Select  the data you want to work with

   [image]
2. `Insert Tab` `->` `Pivot Table` or alternatively press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
3. Edit the Pivot Table settings (by default on right) to match your criteria. In your case:

   [image]
4. After filtering for Vegetables, it provides the expected result:

   [image]

Comment: This is what I looking for.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put this in G2 then fill right and down.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($2:$9)/($A$2:$A$9=$H$1), ROW(1:1))), TEXT(,))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes This is What I looking for.. but
just I wonder if this will work with massive data.. because each cell have it own function.. and I need expand the table automatically

Answer (score 0):

H2

```
=INDEX($C:$C,MATCH($G2,$B:$B,0))
```

Drag down.

I2

```
=INDEX($D:$D,MATCH($G2,$B:$B,0))
```

Drag down

[image: data]

Comment: I already try this but the name column didnt update automaticaly.. and each cell have it own function and not suitable with massive data..

Comment: What do you mean by name column doesn't update? Make a dynamic named range from the list on the left and use it as the source for a data validation list dropdown on the right.

Comment: I mean.. for example there is another name vegetable.. we need to write again on column G and so on